# Is there any performance hit to passing "heavy" objects in R?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have a 1 MB data frame. I pass this object to a function 1000 times to do some calculations. In reality I only need one row of the data frame to do the calculations. Is it less computationally intensive if I just send the one row?

Comment: R will not make a copy of the object simply because it's used in a function, but if your function makes a copy, then you're making things "heavy". It really depends on what you're trying to do. It sounds like a simple loop would suffice and would only be accessing one row the object as it exists.

Comment: [Most of the time](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification) R will only make a copy if you modify a variable. Even then, for data.frames if you modify one variable, only the pointer for that variable (not those for the rest of the data) will be reallocated, so if you follow good idioms (preallocate, etc.), you likely won't be using much more memory than necessary. If you're really concerned, [profile your code](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) to make sure you're not worrying about something that's not a bottleneck. If it's a big issue, data.table offers in-place modification.

Comment: do a quick mock with pryr & microbenchmark. best way to learn is by doing.